# Best resource for learning speed up and vectorization tips in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, vectorization

For a beginner to Matlab code optimization, there are some resources but not all very clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best resource is an enquiring mind.

You have in Matlab an excellent tool for quickly prototyping alternative solutions to common computing problems.  In many situations it will be worth your while coding up 2 or more different solutions to the same problem and developing your own understanding of how to make optimal use of Matlab, especially your understanding of how to squeeze out optimal performance for your own problem set.

Don't discard the unfavoured solutions, file them away in your code repository and test again against new releases to figure out what might have changed. Then come back to SO and teach us old dogs the new tricks.

arf, arf

Answer (score 1):

The most standard reference I'm aware of is:

Acklam (2003) "Matlab Array Manipulation: Tips and Tricks"

Available for free online - just google it.

Other good resources are the comp.soft-sys.matlab
newsgroup, stackoverflow, and pretty much anything written by [Loren Shure](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/)

Final point: To get the most out of SO, try posting some answers of your own. Nothing helps you learn the tips and tricks of the trade faster than putting your own code up for peer-review. Even the very process of clicking the "submit answer" button will make you think twice about every line you've written. After submission, you can gain by comparing your answers to those of more experienced users and seeing how they improved on your own methods.

Comment: I agree with most of this.  But I'd caution anyone using a publication which is now nearly 10 years old to take some time to check that its recommendations are still valid.  For example, a lot of the old wisdom about the performance superiority of vectorisation over explicit loops has been made redundant, or at least more questionable, in recent releases of Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

This page have been very helpful for me. Its very clear and straightforward, with nice examples. Recommend it to eveyone stating up with code speedup in Matlab.

http://yagtom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/speedup.html